# if not working for nth line in document

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to make a simple login system with python 3.5. what it does is opens a document with usernames and passwords inside it. the document has a  username on the first line, and the password for that user on the second line. this continues through the document, resulting in usernames on every odd line, and passwords on every even line. the loop goes through all 20 lines (for 10 users) and takes every odd line as a username, and every even line as a password. it goes through, and checks if the username and password are correct. for some reason, it does not work, it just asks to input username, and input password, and doesnt return anything. it is opening the document fine, as it works when i print out the usernames and passwords.

```
username = input('please enter your username')
password = input('please unter your password')

for i in range(0,20,2):
    text_file = open('users.txt','r')
    database = text_file.readlines()
    if username == database[i] and password == database[i+1]:
        print('login accepted')
    else:
        if username == database[i] and password != database[i+1]:
            print('incorrect password')

text_file.close()
```

Comment: You are making this way more complicated than it should be.

Comment: please just answer it @DeliriousSyntax

Comment: you want me to answer your question or give you an easier version of this?

Comment: easier version please @DeliriousSyntax

Comment: First, are you familiar with `dictionaries`?

Comment: not really @DeliriousSyntax

Comment: Do you want the users to create the accounts or are the accounts going to be predetermined?

Comment: predetermined @DeliriousSyntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely problem has more to do with string stripping than anything. Chances are you have a text file like:

```
myusername
mypassword
otherusername
otherpassword
```

and when you're reading it you get:

```
["myusername\n", "mypassword\n", ... ]
```

You can most likely fix this just by using `str.strip` on each line read from the file.

However you have a couple more logic errors than this. Here's one:

```
for i in range(0, 20, 2):
    text_file = open(...)
    database = text_file.readlines()
    # you really want to open the file and read from it EVERY SINGLE LOOP??
```

and also:

```
if username == database[i] or password == database[i+1]:
    # log in if your password is ANYONE'S password, or if your username
    # is ANYONE'S username.
```

In the grand scheme of things, you should be pre-processing the text file to create a dictionary of key-value pairs.

```
database = {}  # empty dict

with open('path/to/textfile.txt') as inf:
    while True:
        try:
            username = next(inf)
            password = next(inf)
        except StopIteration:
            break
        else:
            database[username.strip()] = password.strip()

username_in = input("What's your username? ")
password_in = input("What's your password? ")
if database[username_in] == password_in:
    # login successful
```

But REALLY, you should never ever ever ever be storing passwords in plain text for any reason whatsoever. Good lord, man, do some research on password storage! :)

Answer (score 0):

[Answer by Adam Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33598958/4677621) is great.
I can only add that the line

```
if database[username_in] == password_in:
```

might cause a `KeyError` if there is no such username in your database. You might want to either check if username exists in database before checking passwords or wrap password check in the `try except` block or use `dict.get(key, default)` method to get the password from your database

Here some code:

```
# Pre check
if username_in in database.keys():
    if database[username_in] == password_in:
        # ...
else:
    # No such username in database


# try .. except
try:
    if database[username_in] == password_in:
        # ...
except KeyError:
    # No such username in database


# get with default
# if no default is specified, default is None
if database.get(username_in) == password_in:
```